# How to compare one column's value to multiple values in other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I don't know how to ask this, so I made up an example.
The goal is to compare the value of columns **A** & **B** to the values of *C*,*D* and *E* separately.
If the value is the same or higher (>=) then return '1' else '0'.

```
     A      B     C     D     E
1   101    103   100   101   99
2   102    100   101   99    103
3   100    99    103   100   98
```

The desired outcome would be this:

```
A               B       
C   D   E       C   D   E
1   1   1       1   1   1
1   1   0       0   1   0
0   1   1       0   0   1
```

Ideally I would like a function for this, what's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct compare `A` and `B` to `C, D, E`, and `concat` them together

```
A = df[['C','D','E']].le(df[['A']].values).astype(int)
B = df[['C','D','E']].le(df[['B']].values).astype(int)

pd.concat([A,B], axis=1, keys=['A','B'])

Out[650]:
   A        B
   C  D  E  C  D  E
1  1  1  1  1  1  1
2  1  1  0  0  1  0
3  0  1  1  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use with [`le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) which checks for every column if its equal or less than `A` and then `B`:

```
cols = ['A', 'B']
compare = ['C', 'D', 'E']

for col in cols:
    print(col)
    df[compare].le(df[col], axis=0).astype(int)
```

**output**

```
A
   C  D  E
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  0
2  0  1  1
B
   C  D  E
0  1  1  1
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
```

---

It would be more elegant to make a dict with the column names as key:

```
cols = ['A', 'B']
compare = ['C', 'D', 'E']

dct = {col: df[compare].le(df[col], axis=0).astype(int) for col in cols}

print(dct['A'], '\n')
print(dct['B'])
```

**output**

```
   C  D  E
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  0
2  0  1  1 

   C  D  E
0  1  1  1
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about broadcasting:

```
compares = df[['A','B']].values[:,:,None] >= df[['C','D','E']].values[:,None, :]
compares = compares.reshape(len(df),-1)
pd.DataFrame(compares,
             columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((list('AB'),list('CDE')))
            ).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   A        B      
   C  D  E  C  D  E
0  1  1  1  1  1  1
1  1  1  0  0  1  0
2  0  1  1  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

For example, in your case with `df` being this dataframe

```
     A      B     C     D     E
1   101    103   100   101   99
2   102    100   101   99    103
3   100    99    103   100   98
```

you could perform the following operation to compare A to C,D and E:

```py
df[['C', 'D', 'E']].apply(lambda x: df['A'] >= x)
```

This will give you:

```py
C        D        E     
True     True     True     
True     True     False   
False    True     True
```

With `True = 1` and `False = 0`. You could do the same to compare B to C,D and E. I hope this helps.